# pip3 can't install setupdocx without setuplib, but can't install setuplib without setupdocx?

Tags: python, module, pip, installation

I appear to be having a chicken and egg problem here. I'm trying to install setupdocx with the command:

```
sudo pip3 install setupdocx
```

and I recieve the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuplib'

So I try to install setuplib with the command:

```
sudo pip3 install setuplib
```

and I recieve the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setupdocx'

I'm completely lost as to how I'm supposed to install these 2 modules. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try installing one of them using apt `sudo apt-get install python3-setuplib` or `sudo apt-get install python3-setupdocx`